# Polymorphic associations to model has_many with different types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, model

I'm learning Rails and currently working on my first application.

I have a Chapter that has_many Activities. There are different types of activities and they all have very different attributes. I have a base Activity and different subclasses to represent each activity type.

I'm having issues modeling this scenario without using STI (since I don't want a single table with many null columns). I read about polymorphic associations but I'm not sure how to use this feature to model this situation (I'm not even sure if this scenario is a good fit for polymorphic associations).

Has anyone modeled something like this using this feature?

Comment: Why not use a json field to keep theses different attributes? If you no want choose this, show your DER and let me see what I can do for you.

Comment: If activities all have very different attributes, I would not use STI and Polymorphic. That is to say, I would not make activities inherit from a base activity. I would make a concern for common methods of activity and include it in each activity class. However, it will be better for getting a solution if you can post more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one table for each activity type, you can do the following :

- Create one class per activity type. They all have to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`
- Implement common activity behavior in a module and include this module every activity class.
- Use a `belongs_to :chapter` relation in every activity class
- Use one `has_many` relation per activity class in the chapter class

If you need helpers to access all activities at once from a chapter, you will have to implement it by yourself with a SQL union for instance.

Comment: I was thinking about making something like this. The order in which activities are added to a chapter matter though so I guess that I'll need to change the relationship for a has_many_through and add an order field in this new third model.